# Google maps js api. Many maps on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have accordion (twitter-bootstrap), and on each I have a map. 
Accordion blocks generates in foreach. Maps generates as partial view, that takes model with latitude and longitude and block id.

It calls in foreach:

```
@if (item.Latitude != null)
{
    <p>Map:</p>
    <div class="map-margin">
         @{Html.RenderAction("Map", "Default", new {model = item});}
    </div>
}
```

And action returns this partial view:

```
@model MPS.Administration.Models.ReportModel

<div id="map-canvas-@Model.Id.ToString()" style="width: 470px; height: 270px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#map-canvas-@Model.Id').ready(function() {
        initialize();
    });

    function initialize() {

        var lat = @Model.Latitude;
        var lng = @Model.Longitude;

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.Latitude, @Model.Longitude);
        debugger;

        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var name = 'map-canvas-' + @Model.Id.ToString();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(name),mapOptions);

        debugger;

        // create a marker
        var image = '../Content/Images/map_icon.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
    }
</script>
```

On layout I included script for js api.

Now I have 4 blocks, but only the last have map block (and it have only `google` logo and gray background without the map :( ). In debugger I see that lat and lng is same all 4 times. I think the problem is how I call initialize() map. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The map si show only in the visible div. For the other you shuuld see only a grey background and in some case a small portion of the map in the upper left corner.

For see the map in every block you should use `map.resize()`  or better use a genaration function for each time you show a new map. Initialize tipcally is call only when the windows is created and this this case the maps not visible fails